# Can you use relative and absolute imports at the same time with python?

Tags: python, frameworks, package

I am trying to make a modular framework but I'm having problems with some of the import statements.

On their own, the files that are in the framework function fine, but when I create the package and import that to another file, the imports made in the individual files throw an error that the module cannot be found.

If I use relative imports for the package, can the files inside the package use absolute imports? I've never had problems importing things like pandas, but it is throwing an error that pandas cannot be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use them mixed up but that is discouraged of course. The best is to always use absolute imports.
Read more about that in the PEP8 docs:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports